# angular and mvc 4 post File to server

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, razor

I have a code like this :

Javascript

```
$scope.saveChanges = function (bl) {
            console.log(bl)
            $http.post('@Url.Action("SaveChangesBudgetLine", "FinancialPlanning")', {
                amount: bl.Amount,
                month: bl.Month.id_bulan,
                year: bl.Year,
                newFile : bl.newFile
            })
            .then(function (resp) {
                console.log(resp)
            })
        }
```

c# :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveChangesBudgetLine(String amount, int month, int year, HttpPostedFileBase newFile)
        {
            return Json(new { is_success = true, amount = amount, month = month, year = year, newFile = newFile });
        }
```

`newFile` in javascript has value like this (console.log on client) :

```
newFile: File
lastModified: 1440754532970
lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 28 2015 16:35:32 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
name: "External.xlsx"
size: 964223
type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

but on server newFile is null.

why this happend? how to solve this case? thanks